How to create a ReGex that matches separated words inside a square brackets?
I have the following string:

[I need some fresh air H2O].

What's the RegEx that matches the following words?

I, need, some, fresh, air, H2O.

Basically, each word inside the square brackets. I searched everywhere, couldn't find it. Every result points to a whole match, such as I need some fresh air H2O (check links below).
Can anyone help?
I'm currently at this RegEx:

(?<=\[).+?(?=\])

But it captures the whole sentence:

I need some fresh air H2O

I'm using the https://regexr.com/ engine (I assume it's javascript), but any engine pattern would suffice.
Related Questions
Regular expression to extract text between square brackets
regex include text inside brackets

Do you mean like this? (?<=\[[^\][]*)[^\s\][]+(?=[^\][]*]) https://regex101.com/r/6Nb9g6/1

@Thefourthbird Perfect! It would be interesting if an answer could unravel this pattern, just for completeness purposes! It could help someone else. It would be even better if another expression that works within most engines were shown

This regex works with Javascript if a lookbehind assertion is supported. If that is not supported, you can capture what is between the square brackets and then split the group 1 values on 1 or more whitespace characters like \[([^\][]+)] https://regex101.com/r/QOKS9r/1

Aside: it's "RegExp" (in JS land), or "regex" or "regexp".

If a positive lookbehind is supported, you could use:
(?<=\[[^\][]*)[^\s\][]+(?=[^\][]*])

The pattern matches:

(?<=\[[^\][]*) Postive lookbehind, assert a [ char to the left followed by optional chars other than [ or ]
[^\s\][]+ Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than [ or ] in between
(?=[^\][]*]) Positive lookahead, assert a ] char to the right preceded by  optional chars other than [ or ]

Note that \s can also match a newline.
See a regex demo.


const regex = /(?<=\[[^\][]*)[^\s\][]+(?=[^\][]*])/g;
[
  "[I need some fresh air H2O]",
  "this is a test 1",
  "this is a [ test 2",
  "this is a ] test 3",
  "[   I need some fresh air H2O 2   ]",
  "[]"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)));




If a lookbehind assertion is not supported, you could use a capture group matching at least a single non whitespace character except for a square bracket in between.
\[\s*([^\][]*[^\s\][][^\][]*?)\s*]

See a regex demo.


const regex = /\[\s*([^\][]*[^\s\][][^\][]*?)\s*]/;
[
  "[I need some fresh air H2O]",
  "this is a test 1",
  "this is a [ test 2",
  "this is a ] test 3",
  "[   I need some fresh air H2O 2   ]",
  "[]"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1].split(/\s+/));
  }
});




You can use str.slice(1, -1).split(/\s+/) or match() method using:

/\b\w+\b/g: \b is a word boundary.

/[^\[\]\r\n\s]+/g: means all chars except those included in the [].




let str = "[I need some fresh air H2O]";
console.log(str.match(/\b\w+\b/g));
console.log(str.slice(1, -1).split(/\s+/));
console.log(str.match(/[^\[\]\r\n\s]+/g));



Prints
[ 'I', 'need', 'some', 'fresh', 'air', 'H2O' ]
[ 'I', 'need', 'some', 'fresh', 'air', 'H2O' ]
[ 'I', 'need', 'some', 'fresh', 'air', 'H2O' ]



It's rather simple to match all words in a string: \w+
\w matches alphanumeric characters and underscores. This assumes that you use a "global search" which repeatedly applies the pattern on the remaining string after each match. In javascript this would be /\w+/g.

This approach works with the example phrase, but wouldn't with other common words — e.g. any compound word with a hyphen (trade-off) or a contraction using an apostrophe (won't) — they'd be split into multiple parts.

right, this answer only works if we trust that OP did choose the example carefully and wants to extract only alphanumeric words. There's lots of assumptions one could make about the input that would require more complicated solutions. For example I also have the feeling that the given string might not be the whole input and could appear within a larger text. Or maybe it doesn't and OP was just thinking too complicated when coming up with the regex

If this doesn't need to be pure regex, it's probably best to just grab the sets of words between brackets first and then string split on a space to get the list of words.


const input = `Some text that's happening [I need some fresh air H2O] and more text and [It's more text inside brackets] blah blah blah`;

function getWordsFromBrackets(str){
  const matches = str.match(/(?<=\[)[^\]]+/g)
  
  console.log('Matches array holds the text of both matched groups: ', matches);
  
  //Join matches with a space to create one long string of the matched words, then split on space to get those words as an array result
  return matches.join(' ').split(' ')
}

console.log("Here's the result: ", getWordsFromBrackets(input));



